# Create macOS High Sierra and newer bootable recovery partition on a separate standalone disk

Tags: macos, partitioning, disk-cloning, recovery

There are manuals on cloning the recovery partitions to a separate disk for any macOS or OS X version prior to High Sierra, but I can google nothing about creating a standalone recovery disk for High Sierra and higher.

Is it possible for APFS based macOSs? Are there any manuals?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/417908/create-macos-high-sierra-and-newer-bootable-recovery-partition-on-a-separate-sta

Comment: Sounds right. I've discovered the Mac forum after posted my question here. Sorry.